# Flask socketio not working after deployment but is still working on local machine

Tags: python, node.js, flask, deployment, flask-socketio

GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OomyKTm net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED manager.js:112 The error keeps on stacking.

Configure my cors_allowed_origins from "*" to my domain name but it still didn't work. Could it have just been a configuration issue or is it a compatibility between socketio and render.com?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OomyKTm

This URL is most likely to be used on your client side code to access the socket in your backend.

Since it is a local address, it will work fine when tested locally. But not in a production environment, the cloud will not be able to access this local address, resulting the connection failure while connecting to backend.

Try hosting the backend separately onrender, and replace that hosted URL with this local address.
or
Replace that local address with your current app's URL where the server code is being hosted.

Comment: How do you host the backend separately? Also, my domain is https://heartsync.onrender.com/. When you said replace local address with current's app's url, did you mean like this https://heartsync.onrender.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OomyKTm

Comment: No,   I meant that you need to replace (http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OomyKTm) With (https://heartsync.onrender.com/)

Comment: yeah, I don't use 127.0.0.1:5000. I use heartsync.onrender but the error just comes out as 127.0.0.0.1